# Proof of center of symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can you help me finish this proof? This is what I have so far, I don't know if it's correct. Any tips on my writing or others are welcome.

"Prove that, for $n \geq 3 $, the center of $S_n$ only contains $I_n$ (the identity)".

Suppose we have $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $\sigma = (a_1,...,a_k)$.
Let $\varphi \in Z(S_n)$ be such that $\varphi \neq \sigma$. We can do that because $(a_1,...,a_k)(a_1,a_2) \neq (a_1,a_2)(a_1,...,a_k)$, and $(a_1,...,a_k) \notin Z(S_n)$.

Then, we can write $\varphi \sigma = \sigma \varphi$. Multiplying by $\varphi^{-1}$ the both terms we obtain:

$\varphi \sigma \varphi^{-1} = \sigma \varphi \varphi^{-1}$.

We also know that:

$\varphi (a_1,...,a_k) \varphi^{-1} = (\varphi (a_1),...,\varphi (a_k))$.

Then,

$(\varphi (a_1),...,\varphi (a_k)) = \sigma = (a_1,...,a_k)$.

Which means that $\varphi = I_n$.

**New proof:** (I hope this works now)

Suppose $\varphi \in Z(S_n)$ such that $\varphi \neq I_n$. We can assume that $\exists i: \varphi (i) \neq i$ and $\exists j \neq i: \varphi (j) = i$.

Now consider $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $\sigma = (j,k), k \in \{ 1,...,n \} \setminus \{ i,j \}$.

Then, we have the equality $\varphi \sigma = \sigma \varphi$. Computing at $j$:

- $\sigma(\varphi(j)) = \sigma(i) = i$.
- $\varphi(\sigma(j)) = \varphi(k) \neq i$, as $\varphi$ is injective and $k\neq j$.

Then, $\varphi$ must be the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is flawed. Just because $(\varphi(a_1),\ldots,\varphi(a_k)) = (a_1, \ldots, a_k)$, that does not mean that $\varphi$ didn't touch the $a_i$'s; it may have cyclically permuted them.

In addition to cyclically permute the $a_i$ (or actually not doing anything to them), $\varphi$ may permute all the *other* elements of $S_n$ however it likes, and it will still commute with $\sigma$. As an example illustrating both of these flaws, take $n = 5$ with $\sigma = (123)$. Then $\varphi = (123)(45)$ commutes with $\sigma$, and we do have $\varphi\sigma\varphi^{-1} = \sigma$ as you (correctly) claim, but $\varphi$ is not the identity permutation.

Instead of starting with a $\sigma\in S_n$, I would start with a $\varphi\in Z(S_n)$, and if it's not the identity, *construct* (or find) a $\sigma\in S_n$ which doesn't commute with it.